# How can I properly format Hibernate entities for use with ember-data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ember.js, ember-data

We currently use a spring/hibernate/jackson backend in our java applications and are considering  using ember.js as the frontend. We would like to also use ember-data.  The problem is that the JSON format ember-data expects is nothing like what Jackson produces by default.

How can I get Jackson to play nicely with ember-data?  Is there a jsonapi.org serializer out there for Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a blog on this very issue.  http://springember.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/using-ember-data-restadapter-with.html.